# How to use the API subscriptions from AWS Data Exchange?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests, aws-marketplace

So I got access to SimilarWeb ranking API from AWS(https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-clsj5k4afj4ma?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa).

I'm not able to figure out how to pass the authentication or how to give a request to retrieve the ranks for domains.

For ex. how will you pass the request for this URL in python?
URL: https://api-fulfill.dataexchange.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/v1/similar-rank/amazon.com/rank

Answer (score 1):

This particular product does not seem to be available any longer. Generally speaking, an AWS IAM principal with correct IAM permissions, can make API calls against AWS Data Exchange for APIs endpoints. The payload of the API call needs to adhere to the OpenAPI spec defined within the DataSet of the product used. The specific API call is 'SendApiAsset'. The easiest way to think about is to read the boto3 documentation for it, here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dataexchange.html#DataExchange.Client.send_api_asset
Other AWS SDKs have the same call, idiomatic to the specific language.

The managed policy that describes the IAM permissions needed is named AWSDataExchangeSubscriberFullAccess, the dataexchange specific permission needed is 'dataexchange:SendApiAsset'.

The awscli way of making the call is described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dataexchange/send-api-asset.html

The required parameters are: asset-id, data-set-id, revision-id. You will likely also need to provide values for: method and body (and perhaps others also depending on the specific API you are calling.

The content of the 'body' parameter needs to adhere to the OpenAPI spec of the actual dataset provided as part of the product.
You can obtain the values for asset-id, data-set-id and revision-id from the AWS Data Exchange service web console describing the product/dataset.